# I want to add a zero to those values of a coulmn in a dataframe with a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I want to add a zero in front of the values of a column, if the value is smaller than 10.

First I convert the values from int to str and then I try to use the endswith-method but it doesnt work. Its probably a syntax error.

This is my code:

```
df.info () 

if ( not df[df['Minute (Visit)'].astype(str).str.endswith('0')]):
    df['Minute (Visit)'] = '0' + df['Minute (Visit)'].astype(str)
```

[image: This is my output]

And the error Message says:

> The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Minute (Visit)': [10, 0, 2, 5, 23, 150]})

# Solution
df['Minute (Visit)'] = df['Minute (Visit)'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

output

```
  Minute (Visit)
0             10
1             00
2             02
3             05
4             23
5            150
```

Comment: Author specified condition that need to add leading zeros only if values less than `10`

Comment: @bhargav Thanks! The `z.fill(2)` will only add zeros until it reaches the length of 2. For those numbers greater or equal to 10, their lengths are larger than 2 so there is no impact to them

Comment: Hoho sorry...I got it

Comment: @quantscientist could also do `df['sample_col'].apply('{:02}'.format)` - avoiding the creation of an explicit new array of strings first...